# Different map markers for every button

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent

I would like to create a main intent(activity) in which someone can choose a track to follow. When a person clicks a button for a certain track, another intent will appear showing the markers along that track on a google map. There will be a "back" button which will bring you to the previous activity.

My question is... can I use a single map and, depending on the button that is clicked, to add specific markers to the map(and erase the previous ones) or highlight that track? How can I transfer a value from one intent to another?(I thought that all the buttons can start the same intent and depending on the value a specific track will be shown).

Any other ideas are welcomed :)

Comment: All the things that you are thinking can be implemented. Only thing left is that you try them first.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Just call the [`clear()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#clear()) method on your `GoogleMap` object and redraw any markers.

Comment: @PPartisan thanks :) and how can I send a value from one intent to another? And how do I receive it in the second intent?

Comment: You'd use `Intent` extras. I'm sure Gokul Kumar will be able to elaborate in his answer below (or you can look it up, as it's a very common and well documented technique)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can achieve this using single map.

just call clear() on google map object.

and secondly, on button click pass data using intent.putExtra(string,string)

method and read data by parsing bundle object in map activity
and accordingly add markers to your google map.

Comment: how do I receive the data and manipulate it in the second intent?

Comment: //first activity

Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("marker_color","red");
startActivity(intent);

//second activity

//in on create function using bundle object

String color
Bundle save=getIntent().getExtras();
if(save!=null)
{
color=save.getString("marker_color");
}

// and use that color variable for setting marker color